# How to customize a SharePoint 2010 Application Page Ribbon?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ribbon

I know how to customize the ribbon in a List pages, or Site settings page. But how to customize the ribbon on a custom developed SharePoint 2010 Application page?

Comment: Check http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101982/add-ribbon-button-via-javascript. You just have to adapt it to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

SPRibbon API solved the problem 
https://spribbon.codeplex.com/